# Shows consecutive days for user

Tags: sql

I have this data and I am trying to add one column (day_in_row)

```
user_id   date      Action  total_actions
1123    21/06/2018  Pageview    1
3321    20/06/2018  Pageview    6
3321    20/06/2018  Click       2
2122    19/05/2018  Pageview    1
2212    21/06/2018  Pageview    1
2212    20/06/2018  Pageview    1
2212    24/06/2018  Pageview    4
2212    24/06/2018  click       2
3321    21/06/2018  pageview    4
3321    21/06/2018  click       3
3321    17/06/2018  pageview    1
```

and I am trying to add one column (day_in_row)

```
user_id   date      Action  day_in_row  total_actions
1123    21/06/2018  Pageview    1   1
3321    20/06/2018  Pageview    1   6
3321    20/06/2018  Click       1   2
2122    19/05/2018  Pageview    1   1
2212    21/06/2018  Pageview    2   1
2212    20/06/2018  Pageview    1   1
2212    24/06/2018  Pageview    1   4
2212    24/06/2018  click       1   2
3321    21/06/2018  pageview    2   4
3321    21/06/2018  click       2   3
3321    17/06/2018  pageview    1   1
```

I tried with this code but still, it is not good

```
with Help([user_id],[date],action,total_actions,day_in_row,[default],[rank])
AS
(
Select * ,
1 as 'default',
case when datediff(day,isnull(lag(date,1) over (partition by user_id order by user_id, date),date) ,[date]) =1 then 1
else 0 end as 'rank'
From [dbo].[FactDailyUsers]
)
Select *, [default]+[rank]
From Help
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the logic for `day_in_row` and tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You want to subtract a sequential value from the date to identify adjacent dates.  The difference is constant for rows with sequential dates.

In this case you have duplicate dates, so you want to use `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Then the value you want is another application of `dense-rank()`.

Based on the syntax of your code, I'll use SQL Server syntax and functions:

```
select fdu.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by user_id, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date)
                          order by date
                         ) as day_in_row
from (select fdu.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by date) as seqnum
      from FactDailyUsers fdu
     ) fdu;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e80671418b2e2e714e75e76fc6773fc) is a db<>fiddle.